# How can I allow only 2 dots after @ in email validation php using ereg

Tags: php, validation, email, ereg

I am trying to validate email in php using ereg, where I am not allowed to enter more than two dots after @ and it can't begin with any special character, how can I do it.

```
function chk($a)
{

$pattern = "^([A-Za-z0-9\.|-|_]{1,60})([@])";
$pattern .="([A-Za-z0-9\.|-|_]{1,60})(\.)([A-Za-z]{2,3})$";

  if (!@ereg($pattern, $a))
     return false;
  else
       return true;
}
```

Comment: can you try this `$pattern .="([A-Za-z0-9\.|-|_]{1,60})([\.{2}])([A-Za-z]{2,3})$";`

Comment: Thanks but, it still returns valid.

Comment: Let me try and get you better solution.

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and why are you using ereg? `Warning
This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.` I think `preg_match` should work for you.

Comment: apple_boy@gmail.com is valid
apple_boy@gmail.co.uk too is valid
but, apple_boy@gmail.co.uk.xyz is invalid.
I am aware of it, but I need it for my understanding.

Comment: It is perfectly valid to have email addresses at a subdomain, i.e. someone@subdomain.example.co.uk. Therefore, your “only two dots after the @ sign” validation will flag false positives. If this is a lesson in using regular expressions, it’s a poor one.

Comment: Btw, any amount of dots are valid in email addresses. For training purpose ok, but don't exclude legit users from any service you plan to offer. Like `test@eu.west.lol.com` is super valid.

Comment: That's not true in general. Employees at many UK schools have addresses of the form `employee@school.region.sch.uk`, for instance.

Comment: Thanks to all for the suggestions, probably informations. It may be valid to have any number of dots after the @ sign, but for self understanding, what shall be the proper regex to accept only two dots that was the basic question.

Answer (score 3):

Please don't roll your own email validation.

```
if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === true){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I am supposed to use ereg and explode no any inbuilt functions.

Comment: not exactly, need to do without inbuilt functions for understanding ergs better way.

Comment: @hunter You can use inbuilt as well.

Comment: Added an up-vote after this was down-voted (presumably by the OP as they took exception to it). This is a perfectly valid answer and the solution I would have recommended myself.

Comment: @Martin, agree its valid, but I need to do it using ereg.

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/",'test@test.co.in.');
```

Comment: This will possibly match every valid email.

Comment: Thanks @Pratik, I need to try it using ereg. :)

Comment: use `preg_match` instead. ereg is `DEPRECATED`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function custom_email_confirmation_validation_filter( $your_email ) {
   if(!preg_match("/^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/ix", $your_email )){ 
        return 'invalid';
    }
    
  if( substr_count($your_email, '.') > 3){
    return 'invalid 1';
  }
  
  return 'valid';
}

echo custom_email_confirmation_validation_filter('golapk.kkk.khazi@gmail.com');
```